# Computing Impropoer Integral Of Gamma Distribution

Tags: improper-integrals

I am trying to compute

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{E}[X^2] &= \lim_{t\to\infty} \int_{0}^{t} x^2 \frac{\lambda^rx^{r-1}\exp(-\lambda x)}{\Gamma (r)}dx \\[2em]
&= \frac{\lambda^r}{\Gamma (r)} \lim_{t\to\infty} \int_{0}^{t} x^{r+1}\exp(-\lambda x)dx
\end{align*}
$$

I have tried integration by parts for the improper integral, but it is rather messy and does not match my numerical result when I fix $r$ and $\lambda$ to specific values.  I am messing up somewhere and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm misinterpreting the question, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty x^{r+1}\exp(-\lambda x)\text{d} x & = \lambda^{-r-2}\int_0^\infty u^{r+1}\exp(-u)\text{d} u \\
& = \lambda^{-r-2}\Gamma(r+2)
\end{align}
$$
By substitution $x\mapsto \frac x\lambda$. Thus
$$
\begin{align}
\Bbb{E}[X^2] & = \frac{\lambda^r}{\Gamma(r)}\frac{\Gamma(r+2)}{\lambda^{r+2}} \\
& = \lambda^{-2}\frac{\Gamma(r+2)}{\Gamma(r+1)}\frac{\Gamma(r+1)}{\Gamma(r)} \\
& = \frac{r(r+1)}{\lambda^2}
\end{align}
$$